# Перемещение объекта с вращением

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как переместить объект с вращением из точки 10, 0, 0 в 30, 0, 0 и чтобы при перемещении объект крутился и когда он дошёл до точки то его rotation должен быть таким 0, 90, 0 я пробывал через такой код но значения у rotation другие

```
transform.position -= new Vector3(2, 0, 0);
transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * 250 * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: Почему вектор движения не умножается на `Time.deltaTime`?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Забыл (Я бы поправил когда оптимизацию проводил)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из условия задачи абсолютно не ясно, какой из параметров задает все движение: время или скорость, если скорость, то чья именно, скорость вращения или перемещения?

Как ни крути, отталкиваться все равно придется от времени - его проще задать, а потом уже высчитывать конкретные скорости, чем наоборот. Использовал интерполяцию для вращения и для перемещения, хотя второе можно заменить обычным `transform.position += скорость * Time.deltaTime`.

Для, скажем, таких параметров:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получаем такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
public class MoveRotator : MonoBehaviour {
    public float timeToMove;
    public Vector3 targetPosition;
    public Vector3 targetRotation;

    void Start() {
        StartCoroutine(MoveRotate());
    }

    IEnumerator MoveRotate() {
        Vector3 startPosition = transform.position;
        Vector3 endPosition = targetPosition;

        Quaternion startRotation = transform.rotation;
        Quaternion endRotation = Quaternion.Euler(targetRotation.x, targetRotation.y, targetRotation.z);

        float timer = 0;
        while(timer < timeToMove) {
            float t = timer / timeToMove;

            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, endPosition, t);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(startRotation, endRotation, t);

            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

---

### P.S.

Также стоит учитывать, что это **пример в вакууме**, и лично я бы не стал использовать для такого отдельный скрипт, такую корутину лучше запускать из другого класса или вообще использовать [LeanTween](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/leantween-3595), который к тому же бесплатный.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю я знаю решение что поможет вам (я знаю их 2)
Силами самого Unity и того что есть из коробки

```
public Transform target;
void Update (){
// для передвижения
    transform.position = 
        Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, target.position, Time.deltaTime * 2);
// для поворота
transform.rotation = 
        Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation , target.rotation , Time.deltaTime * 2);
}
```

Но советую присмотреться к такой штуке как [DOTween](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/dotween-hotween-v2-27676)

[Видео туториал решения вашей задачи](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4AYUOK3MsKE)

Удачи)

Comment: В чем смысл ответа, если он не решает проблему, цитирую, `значения у rotation другие`?

Comment: а вы с ссылками ознакомились ? с DOTween для начала разберитесь во всеми а потом минусуйте

Comment: Вы для начала ознакомьтесь с правилами сайта, ссылка =/= ответ. Да и по секрету DOTween хуже LeanTween'а.

Comment: Хорошо, про LeanTween буду иметь в виду, но я слышал только про DOTween, потому и написал ибо знаю, что там это легко сделать, а ссылку я дал на туториал где реализовывали такую задачу, а там уже пусть автор вопроса смотрит что лучше.

Comment: Ну так в этом и проблема, ссылка - это не ответ, и место ей в комментариях. Вы не относитесь к минусам, как к оскорблению, это лишь инструмент для оценки ответов.

Comment: Просто я в основном смотрю на ответы и не отвечаю (ибо часто просто не знаю), и там вроде для того что бы писать в комментарий нужно 50 понтонов, потому думаю напишу перемещение кодом, и скину примеры в ссылках. НО на будущее буду помнить что лучше тогда вообще не отвечать :(

Comment: Не надо опускать руки, минус - это не конец света, а просто оценка ответа. Ограничение в 50 баллов я никогда не понимал, поэтому отредактировал ваш пост и поставил плюс (без редактирования нельзя такое провернуть), поздравляю, теперь вы официально можете оставлять комментарии :)

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, теперь я смогу просто комментировать :) И буду отвечать только в том случае, если точно уверен что мой ответ будет всецело полным.

Comment: Да не за что, правда. Можно отвечать и без уверенности - вам, возможно, поставят минус и напишут, что не так, после чего вы можете исправить свой ответ и получить адекватную оценку, удачи! ;)